# Error: "System services not available to Activities before onCreate()" even if I got a onCreate() function

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I try to add Text from an EditText-Element by clicking on an navigation.
I tried to exclude the Access to a ListView-Element, in which the Text should get added, in a Java-Class and also initialized it in my main Activity.
If i now try to click on the Send-Button it crashes do to the Error: "System services not available to Activities before onCreate()". 
How can I fix this? I tried solving it by looking into similar Questions but cant figure it out...
I also tried adding an onCreate-Method to the ListViewSDK-Class.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextMessage;

    ListViewSDK LISTVIEW;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
        //LISTVIEW instanz erstellen
        LISTVIEW=new ListViewSDK();
        //Download Last messages
        //Add messages to MessagesList

    }



    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.send_button:
                    //Send Message to ServerScript
                    //Initialize Inputfield
                    EditText INPUTFIELD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputfield);
                    String MESSAGE = INPUTFIELD.getText().toString();
                    LISTVIEW.ADD_ITEM(MESSAGE);

                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

}
```

ListViewSDK:

```
public class ListViewSDK extends ListActivity {

    //ArrayList mit Strings für die Chatanzeige
    ArrayList<String> ITEMS=new ArrayList<String>();
    //Adapter der die Daten der ListView verwaltet
    ArrayAdapter<String> ADAPTER;
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        ADAPTER=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ITEMS);
        setListAdapter(ADAPTER);
    }
    public void ADD_ITEM(String ITEM){
        ITEMS.add(ITEM);
        ADAPTER.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputfield"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    </ListView>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputfield" app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="48dp" android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"></EditText>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

navigation.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
            android:id="@+id/send_button"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_paper_plane"
            android:title="Send"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `ListViewSDK` instance creation in the `onCreate()` of your `MainActivity`.

In Android, **Never Call The Constructors Of Android Components (`Activities`, `Fragments`, `Service`, `ContentProvider`, `BroadcastReceiver`)**.
They have their own lifecycles and they are instantiated by the Android system. Use an `Intent` to summon them or use the `Context`(depending on what you need) instead of calling the constructor.

Further Reading:
 1. [Intro to `Activities`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities)
 2. [Starting new `Activities`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#java)

Also, you can have an independent `ListView`. You do not to subclass it with a `Lifecycle` having component (like `Activity`). Simply get a `[Recycler View][3]` and your should be okay.